# Order columns based on max value in columns - R dataframe arranging

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, multiple-columns

I have the following dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame("A" = c(NA, NA, 3:10, NA), "B" = c(NA,2:11), "C" = c(2:12))
```

How do I reorder the columns in R based on the max value in each row. So here the column order should be

```
C, B, A
```

as the max value is in col C, the next max is in col B and the last max is in col A.

I've a huge dataframe and need to do this automatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work, using base R:

```
x[names(sort(sapply(x, max, na.rm = T), decreasing = T))]
    C  B  A
1   2 NA NA
2   3  2 NA
3   4  3  3
4   5  4  4
5   6  5  5
6   7  6  6
7   8  7  7
8   9  8  8
9  10  9  9
10 11 10 10
11 12 11 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want.

```
x <- data.frame("A" = c(NA, NA, 3:10, NA), "B" = c(NA,2:11), "C" = c(2:12))
maxx <- sapply(x, function(x) max(x,na.rm = TRUE))
result <- x[,order(-maxx)]
result
    C  B  A
1   2 NA NA
2   3  2 NA
3   4  3  3
4   5  4  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Will such a solution work?

```
x %>% dplyr::arrange(-C,-B,-A)
```

or

```
x %>% dplyr::arrange(desc(C,B,A))
```

Please also see the question: [dplyr arrange() function sort by missing values] ([dplyr arrange() function sort by missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37760580/dplyr-arrange-function-sort-by-missing-values))